# why Revel web framework tutorial app doesnt work

Tags: html, go, revel

I'm a beginner in Go and I want to use the revel web framework to develop web applications.

I followed the tutorial to install and test revel from:
    http://revel.github.io/tutorial/index.html

But when I run the **revel run myapp** command and go to `http://localhost:9000/`,
the page shows an error that says:

> Server Error: Template Execution Error (in app/index.html:23):
>   "footer.html" is an incomplete or empty template
>
> Additionally, an error occurred when rendering the error page:
>   html/template:errors/500.html: "errors/500.html" is an incomplete or
>   empty template

I tried to remove the sentence:

> {{ template "footer.html" .}}

Now it works, but this is not a real solution to the problem.

Has somebody else had this problem before ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Revel, but I installed it and followed [this page](http://revel.github.io/tutorial/firstapp.html) of the tutorial with no issue. What step did you explicitly get to, and what files did you edit?

Comment: hey, i had an error when i tried access to localhost:9000 on "creating an app" step, and i edit the App/index.html file to remove that sentence and it works.

Comment: i removed my go installation, install the last version and it work it, maybe the custom installation for Linux Mint was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a newer Go version 1.2 (not 1.1.2).

[Here](http://technosophos.com/2013/12/02/go-1-2-on-ubuntu-12-10.html) is a small tutorial for Ubuntu.